# Javascript algorithm for a n-ary tree to find node with most children

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

I've been searching for a basic javascript algorithm for this problem but was unable to find one and was unable to create it from scratch.

For example, the node with most number direct and indirect children under him.
So for the data structure below, I would expect node '12' to be returned as it has more decedents than node '11'

```
tree = {
  "id": 1,
"children": [
    {
      "id": 11,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 111,
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "id": 112,
          "children": [
            {
              "id": 1121,
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "id": 1122,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 121,
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "id": 122,
          "children": [
            {
              "id": 8888,
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "id": 5555,
              "children": [
                {
                  "id": 6666,
                  "children": []
                },
                {
                  "id": 121212,
                  "children": []
                }
              ]
            }
            ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

would appreciate any help, as I'm stumped.

Comment: Depends on tree representation. Simplest - max in adjacency list, usual - dfs.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: An image is nice, but what does your tree data structure look like? The solution depends much on that structure...

Comment: @trincot its a hierarchy structure, let's call it manager with most employees

Comment: Please specify explicitly what the implemented data structure is. A "hierarchical structure" is still quite vague and does not tell us what your data structure is.

Comment: @trincot added the data structure

Comment: why not node with `id: 1`?

Comment: @NinaScholz I would like to exclude the root, otherwise I would always just return the root.

Answer (score 2):

You could map the dept for each root children and reduce the array by taking the one with most children.

```js
const
    getC = ({ children }) => children?.reduce((sum, node) => sum + getC(node), 1) || 1,
    findNodeWithMostChildren = node => node.children
        .map((node) => [node, getC(node)])
        .reduce((a, b) => b[1] > a[1] ? b : a)
        [0],
    tree = { id: 1, children: [{ id: 11, children: [{ id: 111, children: [] }, { id: 112, children: [{ id: 1121, children: [] }, { id: 1122, children: [] }] }] }, { id: 12, children: [{ id: 121, children: [] }, { id: 122, children: [{ id: 8888, children: [] }, { id: 5555, children: [{ id: 6666, children: [] }, { id: 121212, children: [] }] }] }] }] };

console.log(findNodeWithMostChildren(tree));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This returns the number of the children on the node with the most of them, not the node object (or its id).

Comment: Thanks, that's probably more in line with what the OP was looking for, although I still think their question is unclear (should include the actual data structure not a picture).

Comment: Btw I would not expect the `node` argument to be nullish, so no reason to use `?.` - just `node.children ?? []` (or even without the `?? []` if nodes are guaranteed to have an empty array) should suffice

Comment: @NinaScholz does this answer for indirect descendants as well?

Comment: what doo you mean with *indirect descendants*?

Comment: @NinaScholz, look at the original question, I've added a data structure and expected result